# ¿Por qué no guarda las imagenes que se sube desde mi pagina web a mi servidor local?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

He estado haciendo una pagina donde el usuario suba fotos, el problema radica que en mi base de datos la imagen no se guarda, la columna de la respectiva tabla donde se guarda las imagenes queda en blanco, ni siquiera aparece un "null"

[image]

En esta imagen que subí muestra que el primer registro ya tiene una imagen guardada, pero porque lo subí directamente desde el phpmyadmin, el resto lo he intentado subir desde la pagina que hice con HTML,CSS y PHP, pero el resultado es este; las celdas aparecen en blanco en la columna "byte"

Este es mi codigo php:

```
<?php
  $conec = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "galeria");

  if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $nombre_img = urlencode($_FILES['imagen']['name']);
    $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
    $imagen_tmp = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `img`(`id_users`, `name`, `descripcion`, `name_img`, `type_img`, 
    `byte`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $consulta = mysqli_prepare($conec, $sql);

    // Asignar valor a $id_users
    $id_users = 1;

    // Leer el contenido binario de la imagen
    $imagen_binaria = file_get_contents($imagen_tmp);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta, 'issssb', $id_users, $nombre, $descripcion, 
    $nombre_img, $tipo, $imagen_binaria);

    $resultado = mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);

    if ($resultado) {
       echo "FUNCIONA";
       // Crear el directorio "uploads" si no existe
       if (!file_exists('uploads')) {
          mkdir('uploads', 0777, true);
      }

       // Mover la imagen al directorio de tu servidor
       $ruta_destino = __DIR__ . "/uploads/" . $nombre_img; // Ruta en el servidor
          if (move_uploaded_file($imagen_tmp, $ruta_destino)) {
            echo "Imagen movida exitosamente.";
          } else {
            echo "Error al mover la imagen.";
          }
   } else {
    echo "Error al guardar los datos.";
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Y este es el formulario:

```
 <form action="comprobacion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Introducir nombre de la foto" name="nombre">
            <input type="file" value="Subir foto" name="imagen">
            <label for="historia"> Descripción de la foto
                <textarea name="descripcion" rows="4" cols="40" id="historia"></textarea>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="save">
        </form>
```

No sé sí sea normal eso, pues he hecho una carpeta llamada "uploads", allí si se guardan las imagenes, pero dentro del servidor no se guardan y quiero saber el porqué. Si me ayudarán con este error se los agradecería mucho

Comment: Se suben las imágenes pero lo que no se guarda es el nombre o ruta en la DB? Es así?

Comment: @OCHOA gracias por comentar. Lo que no se guarda es la cantidad de byte de las imagenes. El nombre si se guardan correctamente (el campo "name_img" es la que guarda los nombres de las imagenes) y la ruta pues no estoy buscandola guardar.

Comment: Las imagenes se guardan en una carpeta que hice llamada "uploads", pero yo quiero además que se guardén allí en el mi servidor local para luego hacer posteriores operaciones con esas imagenes (como mostralas al usuario, eliminarlas de su lista de imagenes, etc..)

Comment: Pero porque las imágenes en dos lados? Es más, no es recomendable guardar las imágenes en la DB. Si o si las **Necesitas** en la DB??

Comment: No, no necesariamente las necesito guardar en la DB, lo estoy haciendo así porque supuse que debía hacerlo así. Es la unica forma que se me ocurrio para trabajar con imagenes.

El guardar las imagenes en una carpeta aparte fue un consejo que me dió otra persona, pero no entiendo como realizar operaciones de esa forma como mostrar la imagen o eliminarla sí así lo desee el usuario. Pero guardandola directamente en la DB ya tenía una ídea (con referente a la id de la imagen y así hacer todas las operaciones que tenía en mente), es por eso que quería guardarla en la DB

Answer (score 0):

( •̀ ω •́ )✧

Personalmente no recomiendo guardar las imagenes directo en la base de datos debido a que luego se podria sobrecargar o causar problemas con un gran volumen de datos.

En tu código, todo parece estar en orden, pero creo que tienes un detalle con el manejo de los archivos binarios.

En tu código, estás leyendo el contenido del archivo con la función `file_get_contents()` que devuelve un string, y luego tratas de guardar ese string como un blob en MySQL. MySQL puede tener problemas para convertir este string en un blob, especialmente si el string contiene caracteres no ASCII.

Para guardarlo te recomiendo que primero codifiques el archivo algo así:

```php
// Leer el contenido binario de la imagen
$imagen_binaria = file_get_contents($imagen_tmp);

// Codificar el contenido en base64
$imagen_binaria = base64_encode($imagen_binaria);
```

Y luego para mostrar la imagen necesitarias decodificar el contenido algo así:

```php
// Obtener el contenido del blob de MySQL
$imagen_binaria = /* El contenido del blob de la base de datos */;

// Decodificar el contenido base64
$imagen_binaria = base64_decode($imagen_binaria);

// Mostrar la imagen
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $imagen_binaria;
```

Comment: Disculpa, pero aún sigue sin aparecerme los byte de las imagenes en la base de datos, este es el codigo que he agregado:

` // Leer el contenido binario de la imagen
    $imagen_binaria = file_get_contents($imagen_tmp);
 //Imagen en base64
    $imagen_codificada = base64_encode($imagen_binaria);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta, 'issssb', $id_users, $nombre, $descripcion, 
    $nombre_img, $tipo, $imagen_codificada);
    $resultado = mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);`

Pero me gustaría saber que otro enfoque me recomendarías para guardar las imagenes e intentar de esa forma.

Comment: Te sugerimos revisar [answer]

Answer (score 0):

En base a:

> No, no necesariamente las necesito guardar en la DB, lo estoy haciendo así porque supuse que debía hacerlo así. Es la unica forma que se me ocurrio para trabajar con imagenes. El guardar las imagenes en una carpeta aparte fue un consejo que me dió otra persona, pero no entiendo como realizar operaciones de esa forma como mostrar la imagen o eliminarla sí así lo desee el usuario. Pero guardandola directamente en la DB ya tenía una ídea (con referente a la id de la imagen y así hacer todas las operaciones que tenía en mente), es por eso que quería guardarla en la DB

Guardas en la DB solo la url y luego llamas a la imagen. Es lo más conveniente.

Mira este ejemplo: Partimos del hecho que tu formulario de subida usa el método `POST` y que el campo tipo `file` de la imagen tiene como `id` y `name` imagen.

```
<?php
// Insertando imagen a un empleado
$empID = $_POST['envio_de_form']; // Este es el ID de mi registro en la DB
# definimos o creamos la carpeta destino para las Imagene por ID de empleado
$carpetaDestinoImagen = "archivos/docs/".$empID."/";
@mkdir($carpetaDestinoImagen);
# si hay algun archivo que subir en el envio del POST
if($_FILES["imagen"]["name"][0]){
    # recorremos todos los arhivos que se han subido
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["imagen"]["name"]);$i++){
        # si exsite la carpeta o se ha creado
        if(file_exists($carpetaDestinoImagen) || @mkdir($carpetaDestinoImagen)){
            $extension = explode(".",$_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i]);
            $origenImagen= $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            $nameImagen = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i];
            $urlImagen= $carpetaDestinoImagen.sha1(uniqid($nameImagen)).".".$extension[1];

            echo 'Origen >> '.$origenImagen.'<br>';
            echo 'URL >> '.$urlImagen.'<br>';
            echo 'Nombre >> '.$nameImagen.'<br>';
            echo 'Extension >> '.$extension[1].'<br>';

            /*
               En base a las variables anteriores,
               (pueden ser más, dependiendo de la información que tu necesites)
               haces el insert en tu Base de Datos,
               el insert de la url ($urlImagen) obviamente.
            */

            # movemos el archivo
            if(@move_uploaded_file($origenImagen, $urlImagen)){
                echo 'Imagen <b>'.$nameImagen.'</b> Movida Correctamente con ruta <b>'.$urlImagen.'</b><br>';

            }
            else{ // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
                echo 'Error al Subir Imagen<br>'; // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
            } // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
        }
        else{ // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
            echo 'Error en Carpeta Imagen<br>'; // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
        } // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
    }
}
```