# Problemas con codigo al subir imagenes a mi servidor PHP

Tags: php, php8

tengo un problema con mi codigo para subir imagenes a mi servidor, el codigo funciona correctamente, pero el problema es si la imagen ya existe con ese mismo nombre, no la sube, o si excede cierto tamaño no la sube, quisiera que mi codigo convirtiera el tamaño de la imagen y la renombre automaticamente para que no se repita y se suban todas las imagenes sin problema alguno, he intentado de todo, he buscado tutoriales pero no he conseguido hacerlo ya que no tengo mucho conociento en php.

Este es mi codigo:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  // File upload configuration
  $targetDir = "uploads/";
  $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

  $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = '';
  $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';
  $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesASQL = '';
  $fileNames = array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']);
  if(!empty($fileNames)){
    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){
      // File upload path
      $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
      $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

      // Check whether file type is valid
      $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(
          move_uploaded_file(
            $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath
          )
        ){
          // Image db insert sql
          $insertValuesSQL .= "('". $fileName . "', NOW(), LAST_INSERT_ID()),";
        }else{
          $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | ';
        }
      }else{
        $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | ';
      }
    }
    // Error message
    $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?
      'Upload Error: '.trim($errorUpload, ' | '):
      '';
    $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?
      'File Type Error: '.trim($errorUploadType, ' | '):
      '';
    $errorMsg = !empty($errorUpload)?
      '<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:
      '<br/>'.$errorUploadType;

    if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){
      $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL, ',');
      // Insert image file name into database
      $inser_propiedad = mysqli_query($db, 
"INSERT INTO 
   propiedades (
     tipo, precio, nombre, descripcion, ciudad, calle, cp,
     colonia, created, author, altura, metros2, recamaras,
     banos, estacionamiento, mascotas, hijos, tipo_p
   ) VALUES (
     '$typep', '$pricep', '$titlep', '$descp', '$ciudadp', '$callep',
     '$cpp', '$clp', '".time()."', '".$myuser->id."', '$altp','$m2p', '$rcp',
     '$bnp', '$estacionamientop', '$mascotasp', '$ninosp', '$typeprop'
   )"
      );

      $cadena = "
INSERT INTO visit_days (id, dia, visit, hora_inicio, hora_termino) VALUES ";

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($visit_day); $i++){
        $cadena .= "(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$visit_day[$i].
          "', '".$dia[$i]."', '".$horai[$i]."', '".
          $horaf[$i]."'),";
      }

      $cadena_final = substr($cadena, 0, -1);
      $cadena_final.=";";
      if (mysqli_query($db, $cadena_final)) {
        header("Location: " . $web_settings['weblink'] . "mispropiedades.php");
      }else{
        echo 'No';
      }

      foreach($field_values_array as $value){
        $insertad = mysqli_query($db, 
        "INSERT INTO amenidades (id, nombre) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$value')"
        );
      }

      $insert = mysqli_query($db,
      "INSERT INTO images (file_name, uploaded_on, id2) VALUES $insertValuesSQL"
      );

      if($insert){
        header(
          "Location: ".$web_settings['weblink']."mispropiedades.php"
        );
      }else{
        $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
      }
    }else{
      echo "Upload failed! ".$errorMsg;
    } 
  }else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
  }
}
```

Quisiera que me puedan ayudar porfavor

Comment: En PHP puedes usar [`uniqid()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php) para generar valores únicos, así te aseguras de que el nombre nunca se repetirá. Por ejemplo: `$uniqueName = uniqid('unNombre_');` te dará algo parecido a esto: `unNombre_651c9d1abed6e`. O, si quieres incluir la extensión: `$ext='jpg';
$uniqueName = sprintf("%s.%s", uniqid('unNombre_'),$ext);` te dará algo así más o menos: `unNombre_651c9e776ff2d.jpg`. En cuanto a admitir archivos de mayor tamaño, tienes que cambiar la configuración de `upload_max_filesize` en la configuración de PHP.

Comment: No se si sea la causa del problema, pero en la línea 62 del código que pones, no hay manera de que inserte ese registro. Se requieren 3 columnas `(file_name, uploaded_on, id2)` y solo le estás enviando un parámetro; y que lo más seguro sea una cadena, por lo que debería estar entre comillas simples: `'$insertValuesSQL'`.

Comment: [Acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/599579/por-qu%c3%a9-no-guarda-las-imagenes-que-se-sube-desde-mi-pagina-web-a-mi-servidor-lo) te ponen un buen ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano podrias ayudarme en el mismo codigo porfavor, es que voy comenzando en este mundo y se me complica D:

Comment: @Yenn Mi problema no es ese, si funciona todo correctamente, repito mi problema es que si ya existe una imagen con ese nombre de archivo no lo sube, quiero que mi codigo renombre los archivos subidos para que no se repitan y convierta el tamaño de las imagenes.

Comment: Cuando dices "si excede cierto tamaño no la sube", ¿cuál es ese tamaño? Recuerda que en php.ini se establece un tamaño máximo de archivo cuando envias archivos al servidor. Puedes revisar el valor de upload_max_filesize (y cambiarlo, si desarrollas localmente). En cuanto a que no sobrescriba los archivos, podría tratarse de un problema de permisos pues la función move_uploaded_fil() _debe_ sobrescribir archivos. Según el manual: si el archivo es un archivo válido pero no se puede mover por alguna razón, 'move_uploaded_file()' devolverá 'false' y se emitirá una advertencia.

Comment: Pero no es difícil hacer algo como, si ya existe este archivo, pues renombralo en la DB (si es que guardas el nombre ahí) y también al archivo real. Para cambiar el tamaño de imagenes yo tengo un código, si quieres te lo paso como respuesta

Comment: @JuanCarlos Desconozco cual sea el tamaño por eso pongo cierto tamaño y por eso es el motivo de la publicacion para ver si a mi codigo de arriba puedo añadir algo para que automaticamente convierta el tamaño de cualquier imagen y la suba sin problemas

Comment: @Yenn sii porfa me puedes pasar tu codigo

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago así:

```html
<form action="img.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="img">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**img.php** procesa los datos del `form` y por ultimo muestro el resultado.

```php
include_once 'helpers.php';

if ($_FILES["img"]) {
    $uploadFolder = 'img/';
    $tempFile = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileName = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["img"]["type"];
    $urlFile = $uploadFolder.$fileName;

    $saveImg = $helpers->imgCompress($tempFile, $fileType, $urlFile);
}

echo '<center><img src="'.$saveImg.'" /></center>'
```

**helpers.php**

```php
class helpers{
    public function imgCompress($imgTemp, $fileType, $urlFile){
        $imgResult = '';
        // Resolucion Óptima
        $maxWidth = 1280;
        $maxHeight = 900;
        // Tamaño Img
        $imgSize = getimagesize($imgTemp);

        if($imgSize[0] < 1280){
            move_uploaded_file($imgTemp, $urlFile);
            $imgResult = $urlFile;
        }
        else {
            //Redimensionar
            $imgOriginal = $imgTemp;

            if($fileType =='image/jpeg'){
                $newImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgOriginal);
            }
            else if($fileType =='image/png'){
                $newImg = imagecreatefrompng($imgOriginal);
            }

            list($width,$height) = getimagesize($imgOriginal);

            $xRatio = $maxWidth / $width;
            $yRatio = $maxHeight / $height;

            if( ($width <= $maxWidth) && ($height <= $maxHeight) ){
                $widthFinal = $width;
                $heightFinal = $height;
            }
            elseif (($xRatio * $height) < $maxHeight){
                $heightFinal = ceil($xRatio * $height);
                $widthFinal = $maxWidth;
            }
            else{
                $widthFinal = ceil($yRatio * $width);
                $heightFinal = $maxHeight;
            }

            $imgCreate = imagecreatetruecolor($widthFinal,$heightFinal);

            imagecopyresampled($imgCreate,$newImg,0,0,0,0,$widthFinal,$heightFinal,$width,$height);

            if($fileType == 'image/jpeg'){
                imagejpeg($imgCreate,$urlFile);
            }
            else if($fileType == 'image/png'){
                imagepng($imgCreate,$urlFile);
            }
            $imgResult = $urlFile;
        }
        return $imgResult;
    }
}

$helpers = new helpers();
```

Esto me pasa de una imagen FHD y muy pesada como esta

[image: CoC]

A algo más razonable como esto

[image: CoC]

PD: Puedes ver la diferencia entre las dos imágenes viéndolas por separado en otra pestaña